# Can't install Ubuntu from USB, the screen resizes and stops

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

I know there were a lot of this questisons, but I haven't found solution anywhere for my particular problem. I have Windows 8 now and I want to delete it all and instal Ubuntu. I made USB Boot containing lastest version of Ubuntu and tried to install it, but I only get Ubuntu screen, and when I choose "Install Ubuntu". The screen gets smaller and it stops.

I used Unetbootin and Universal USB Boot Installer, also checked on various pendrives. None of them work.

Here are the screenshots : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is that really Ubuntu 14.04????

Comment: Yes, my iso : ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso. When I installed it using Unetbootin it look a little bit different.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that either you downloaded a corrupted file or unetbootin failed to set your pen drive in the proper way.

First use m5checksum on the Ubuntu*.iso file you downloaded and verify the number matches the original one (all this info should be in the Ubuntu download page)

If the iso is working fine, use unetbootin to create a new booting pen drive and try again.

Good luck

Edit: I see you used different pen drives... So my guess is only about the iso

Comment: I will check m5checksum now, but the problem is that I downloaded various versions (Mint also) of Ubuntu, using various programs so I don't think the problem lays here. I think it is something with Windows 8.

Comment: I have checked m5sum, it is correct.

Comment: I found unlikely w8 to be involved. The pen drive boots so everything happens before windows starts.  if checksum is fine, I will investigate hardware problems: is the BIOS preventing to install from pen drive?

Comment: Somehow it is, I have to press F8/F10/Del keys from the beggining so this boot starts. If not, the screen is getting blank for 1 minutes and then starts W8 normally.

Comment: I have changed to UEFI USB Boot, but the only difference is that diffrent Ubuntu console is showing up.

Comment: What do you mean different console? Can you try Ubuntu without installing(first option)? I am not sure, but can you post your hardware specs (especially ram)? Maybe there is a problem with the drivers at some level?

Comment: Apparently windows 8 messed up few things with shutdown and hibernations... http://askubuntu.com/questions/531056/unable-to-access-windows-8-1-hard-drive-in-ubuntu-14-04     If this is the case, try to Restart w8 with the pen drive in. Press f12 to select the booting drive and cross your fingers

Comment: Different console : I mean for UEFI there is other layout for starting boot. I cannot do anything with this boot. However, it works on laptop. I think the problem is with hardware, I tried to plug monitor to motherboard only but it didn't worked. Thanks for replies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17559/discussion-between-gmz-and-kodw).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Apparently there is an issue with Ubuntu and uefi systems. Set the bios to no uefi AND disable secure boot. Have a look at point 1-3 in the link for more info.

Comment: Thanks but I have already checked this UEFI, I have no such things in BIOS as "Secure Boot" or "no uefi"

Comment: Well. First thing is to remove the uefi usb boot option. Then, the other options names may change depending on the maker. I will suggest to check for SATA drive options, something like "compatible mode" or "enhanced mode", as these may prevent the pen drive from recognising your hardware...

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow Ubuntu to totally take over the HDD?  If so, you need to change the boot sequence and remove the USB drive from the boot sequence.

I still have the ISO on a disk, but I boot totally from the HDD where I gladly allowed Linux to totally replace Windows.

Don't forget to upgrade and update the repositories in the Terminal after the install.

Comment: What do you mean by taking over the HDD? I can't do it without proper running console I guess

Comment: On your screenshot, I notice there was an option to "Boot from first hard disk [HDD]"  Did you try selecting that?

Comment: I didn't, I will try it after I check another solution I have found : http://superuser.com/a/678325

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found finally the solution. I needed to set SATA to AHCI and External Sata to Disable